# MVC based authentication templates in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core

When creating a new ASP.Net Core web project in ASP.Net Core 2.0, and choosing the 'Individual account' authentication option, the authentication views/controllers where originally implemented using ASP.Net MVC.  Recently it appears they have been updated to use Razor pages.  My questions is...is there a way I can revert the new project template to using the MVC instead of Razor pages or at the very least is there a way I can see what code the MVC template used to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, no. Identity now comes with a Razor Class Library containing a default UI, which as you've noted, is Razor Pages-based. If you want the old-style MVC setup, you'll need to create it yourself. You can scaffold the Default UI pages into your project and then refer to these to move code into controllers/views. Then, when you're done with that, remove the default UI pages in your project, and turn off the default UI in general by using `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>` (which adds the default UI under the hood).

FWIW, I used to be totally opposed to Razor Pages until I endeavor the same thing you're about to embark on. After moving all the code into controllers, I started to remember how much of a mess it actually was. There's so much boilerplate code involved in auth: sign in, sign out, registration, password resets, 2FA, third-party login, etc. You end up with monstrous controllers with hundreds or even thousands of lines of code. Even if you try to break it up into many different controllers, that just kind of makes it worse. Long and short, Razor Pages actually works pretty well for something like this. It keeps each unit of functionality self-contained, so you know exactly where your need to go to edit stuff. I'd encourage you to give it a go as-is, first, and see how it works for you.

Also, one of your main concerns may be the Web Forms style of routing with Razor Pages, where you the path becomes the URL, and if you're like me, that probably offends your sensibilities. This can actually be changed, though it's not documented well at all. You can simply specify whatever route you'd like the page to have with the `@page` directive. For example, you could do something like following in `Login.cshtml`:

```
@page "/signin"
```

Then, you can access the page via `/signin`, instead of `/Identity/Account/Login.cshtml`.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.  I guess my next question is, say I still really wanted to get the sourcecode for the original mvc based templates where could I get these?

Comment: I'm not sure it exists. It was part of the project scaffold in Visual Studio, which I don't think was open source.